# 'these five years' vs. 'the last/past five years'

Tags: expressions

Let me confirm my understanding.

(1) I have been working *for the last/past five years*. (correct)

(2) I have been working *for these five years*. (incorrect)

(3) I have been working *these five years*. (correct but archaic)

Is this understanding correct? Are there other expressions corresponding to (1)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do those symbols in parentheses mean? Correct, incorrect?

Comment: cross (x), in any language is 'incorrect'... correct me if my opinion is 'incorrect!' :P

Comment: I'm so sorry. I edited my post.

Comment: All three examples seem to sound okay to my ear. I don't understand why any of them would need to be marked as "archaic". Perhaps in a specific context, then the versions could be marked as to their level of acceptability.  Also, I can easily see someone saying, *"I have been working for these last five years"*, and I would consider that to be okay too.

Answer (score 1):

That understanding is correct. You can also say "I have been working for five years," and it is implied that it is referring to the most recent five years.

Answer (score 0):

All three are acceptable to me. In my experience as an American English speaker, 2 and 3 are not very common. Another simple and direct way to put it would be "I have been working for five years."